# Nhibernate use extension functions in Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have written a Query:

```
from order in session.Query<ORM.Entities.Order>()
                                  where order.Finishable()
                                  select order);
```

where Finishable is a method containing some business logic which returns a bool.

Nhibernate is returning a System.NotSupportedException: Boolean Finishable() exception.

The logic in Finishable() is a bit more complex. So my questions are:

1. What can I do to allow the use of custom functions in queries? Do i have to change the signature of the method?
2. Is it even a good idea to do it in this way? I could also try to rewrite the logic to work with nhibernate. This would result in duplicating the logic somehow. Is this unavoidable in this case?
3. I could also try to fetch all data necessary to compute Finishable() afterwards, so first get all Orders and fill them with data, and after that i could use my function as is.

So what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any actual named function that you write is going to be compiled by the compiler, and thus effectively unusable by the LINQ query provider.

You need to create an `Expression` that represents the operation that you have.

You almost certainly want to use a lambda to create that expression, but you don't necessarily need to always *inline* those lambdas, as is typical.  You can create a method/property/field that stores an expression you wish to expose to a larger scope:

```
public class Order
{
    //consider renaming as appropriate
    public static Expression<Func<Order, bool>> Finishable
    {
        get
        {
            //TODO change logic in lambda as needed
            return order => order.Status == "Finished";
        }
    }
}
```

You can then write:

```
var query = session.Query<ORM.Entities.Order>()
    .Where(ORM.Entities.Order.Finishable);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. To realize this approach I have to recursively modify every function and convert them to Expressions. In a more general case, is this always the best approach? Are the cases, where this would not be possible? For me it feels like this would lead to a more complicated model, where the implementation is governed by a specific Framework used.

Comment: @Kalkas You're going to need to have the logic in `Expression` objects for the query provider to support them, yes.  How, specifically, you go about creating those expressions can vary widely, and the specifics of how you should be doing it will depend on the situation at hand.  Yes, dealing with expressions is more complex than just writing C# code; it's the nature of writing C# code that can be interpreted and translated into an entirely separate querying language (particularly one less powerful than C#).  It's just *going* to have some complexity to it.